# ajax call to webmethod doesn't hit success in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have an ajax request in a page say Test.aspx

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/TestMethod",
                data: "{ 'Parameter':'Parameter'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('error getting Regions');
                }
            });
```

and in the code behind

```
   [WebMethod()]
    public static string TestMethod(string Parameter)
    {
      return "teststring";
    }
```

Issue is control is not going in to success inside ajax, any idea?''

Comment: no... updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Testtry this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/TestMethod",
                data: "{ 'Parameter':'Parameter'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) {

                    var s = JSON.stringify(res);
                    alert(s);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error getting Regions');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to make sure you are doing.

First thing you need to add script manager with enable page method property true like below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

See my blog post about [How to call ASP.Net page method with jQuery](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/06/How-to-call-ASP-Net-page-method-with-jQuery.html)

Check the Page URL and everything. It should be correct and should be exactly same as page name and method name as it is case sensitive.

Check parameter also. There is another good post with parameter is also below for your reference.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: we are not alowed to use asp controls in this page

Comment: getting error 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load

Comment: see the following link-http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/